# NWEthernetChannel not working as expected

Tags: swift, network-programming, macos-catalina

The **"Advances in Networking"** talk for WWDC2019 featured a new class, introduced in Mac OS X 10.15 called `NWEthernetChannel` to monitor a custom (non-IP) protocol. This is for MacOS.

I am interested in monitoring [Cisco Discovery Protocol (CDP)](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ehgs/internet/cdp.shtml) packets, however, the class is not working as expected - the `receiveHandler` is not receiving any data.

**What I verified:**

1. `NWEthernetChannel` is alive and in the `ready` state, monitoring the active `NWInterface` called `eth0`.
2. As per the documentation, the `com.apple.developer.networking.custom-protocol` entitlement is set.
3. I verified the same logic using `sudo tcpdump -nn -v -i en0 -s 1500 'ether[20:2] == 0x2000'`. This returned the expected result.

Please see my implementation below:

```
self._ethernetChannel = NWEthernetChannel(on: self._ethernetInterface!, etherType: 0x2000)

self._ethernetChannel!.stateUpdateHandler = {state in switch state {
            case .ready:
                NSLog("ready");
                break;
            case .waiting(let error as NWError):
                print("Waiting:", error);
                break;
            case .failed(let error as NWError):
                print("Failed:", error);
                break;
            case .cancelled:
                print("cancelled");
                break;
            case .preparing:
                print("preparing");
                break;
            case .setup:
                print("setup");
            default:
                NSLog("default");
                break;
                }}
            
self._ethernetChannel!.receiveHandler = {(packetData, vlanTag, localAddress, remoteAddress) in           
     print("received data");
};
            
self._ethernetChannel!.start(queue: .main);
```

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't use `;` at the end of lines in Swift, this is not Obj-C. Also, no need to `break` in a switch statement, since there's no fallthrough in Swift switches (again, this is not Obj-C).

Comment: Thanks! Though after having used Obj-C for the last 13 years and just started with Swift, I am still adapting ;-)